# Statistically convergent: what is $\operatorname{st}$?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $ (X,d) $ be a metric space. A sequence $(x_{k})$ of points in $X$ is said to be statistically convergent to an element $\ell$ of $X$ if, for each positive real number $ \varepsilon $,

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left|\{k\le n : d(x_{k},\ell)\ge\varepsilon\}\right|=0 \,,$$

and this is denoted by

$$\operatorname{st} - \lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}= \ell$$
I don't know $\operatorname{st}$ in definition. What is it. Help me.

I think $\operatorname{st} =(x_{k})$ or $\operatorname{st} =\lim(x_{k})$ ?

Comment: The "st" before lim is a notation that is defined being defined here.

Comment: thank you  so much.

Comment: I'm not sure. st =(x_{k}) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, we're just defining the term
$$
st -\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}= \ell
$$
to mean
$$
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}|\{k\le n : d(x_{k},\ell)\ge\varepsilon\}|=0.
$$

There's nothing special about the specific choice $st$ - we just need to distinguish it from the normal $\lim$. For a similar example, people frequently write $\textrm{plim}_{n\to \infty} X_n = c$ do denote that $X_n$ converges in probability to $c$. In short, it's just notation!

Comment: I want to know meaning of st.

Comment: The meaning is defined in your first equation. If that statement holds, rather than writing that long expression over and over again, we're just gonna say $st-\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \ell$.

Comment: Thank you apprentice so much.

Comment: To clarify, the $-$ is not a minus sign; it's just a dash to connect $st$ with $\lim$.

Comment: should  I write st ?

Comment: You should write it if the sequence satisfies $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}|\{k\le n : d(x_{k},\ell)\ge\varepsilon\}|=0$.